# How can i add a view to a toolbar item in my eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, maven-plugin-development

i'm making a plugin in eclipse and almost finished my plugin. I created a toolbar item and a window(view). I didn't wanna open my view on Window>Show View>Other. When i click on toolbar item, my window should open. 
I'm a newbie in plugin development, so i need your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html

Comment: Views always appear in 'Window > Show View > Other' . You can also show it from your toolbar.

Comment: @Shashwat Thank you, really. This web site is just a treasure!